# How to display html list vertically manageable top to bottom and again top to bottom

Tags: html, css

i want to display the data vertically in HTML list. With following style

```
|AEIM|
|BFJN|
|CGKO|
|DHLP|
```

The data should wrap horizontally. I have following code. I am not sure how its possible If I use float left after 4 entries through PHP it floats to the right bottom not top bottom. Anyone knows how to do it?

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
   <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to make a new `ul` for each column..? http://jsfiddle.net/egpGB/

Comment: Do you know the number of rows per each column? Always 4 rows?

Comment: no because I would be using php mysql to list the data and I dont know the size of the data it could be change day by day. Thats why I want my ul to wrap the data horizontally

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout) is good for this

Comment: @Pinny number of row could be 8.

Comment: Also, do you know how many columns will you have?

Answer (score 1):

Set up 4 `<ul>` and float them to the left. Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zmGpY/ you can then use the wrapping div to clear them

Comment: I have big data. This is just an example to understand if there is any thing we can do.

Comment: So, this isn't the effect you wanted to achieve? If not, tell me what you would like to achieve.

Comment: actually i am making a classified page. It shows state and city list in popup box. I want state and city go up to bottom when it reach to width of box it should wrap to right